# QT 6.6.1 QML compiler error: qmltyperegistration error 1

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've recently started to learn QT and QML and for that I wanted to try my hand at designing something basic in QML.
However, as soon as I make an Qt Quick Application project and try to build it, I receive the following error:

```
:-1: error: [_deps\ds-build\src\imports\application\CMakeFiles\QuickStudioApplication.dir\build.make:85: _deps/ds-build/src/imports/application/quickstudioapplication_qmltyperegistrations.cpp] Error 1
```

I haven't coded anything yet at this point, this occurs at the default project so I'm kinda stuck on where the problem lies.

Is there anyone who has had this issue before, or someone who might have some insight on how to approach this?

Comment: Under what system are you ? Windows (mingw/msvc) ? Linux ?